# Most effective way of storing and managing moderate number of users

Tags: c#

In a current project of mine I need to manage and store a moderate number (from 10-100 to 5000+) of users (ID, username, and some other data).

This means I have to be able to find users quickly at runtime, and I have to be able to save and restore the database to continue statistics after a restart of the program. I will also need to register every connect/disconnect/login/logout of a user for the statistics. (And some other data as well, but you get the idea).

In the past, I saved settings and other stuff in encoded textfiles, or serialized the needed objects and wrote them down. But these methods require me to rewrite the whole database on each change, and that's increasingly slowing it down (especially with a growing number of users/entries), isn't it?

Now the question is: What is the best way to do this kind of thing in C#?

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience in SQL or other query languages (except for a bit of LINQ), but that's not posing any problem for me, as I have the time and motivation to learn one (or more if required) for this task.

Comment: Your question is very broad, and quite probably will be closed as being off topic.  Can you narrow it down to a _specific_ area of concern?

Comment: You *probably* want to get into databases. Start with simple tutorials and you'll soon realize how good it is for your needs.

Comment: 10 is quite different from 5000+, if many of the user's activities are "logged" this difference becomes exponential in terms of the amount of data and load.

Comment: Agree with Jane.  In any case, not sure where the uncertainty lies.  You already call your store of data a database.  You're getting to the point where you need the services of a database engine to deal with your database. Given that this is C# and it comes bundled with development versions of SQL Server in Visual Studio, just take the plunge and start learning SQL Server.  If that is not to your liking for some reason, try something like MongoDb (another path you can go down, NoSQL).

Comment: Also, don't restrict yourself to looking at relational databases, document databases and eventstores might be good solutions to consider.

Comment: @Alex Logging actions of users has the potential to grow indefinitely even with 1 user, so we must assume actions of 3 years ago (or any other threshold) are discarded, and so the amount of storage would be roughly `O(nk)` where `n` is number of users and `k` is average of actions logged for a single user throughout the lifetime of the logging.

Comment: I heard that databases (SQL and others) are rewriting the whole database too, and I don't know if there's a difference between me writing/reading a textfile and the SQL-Database which is doing the same thing basically...

Comment: "... slowing it down , isn't it?" - is the question you have to answer yourself - maybe it is not and you are fine to use whatever you have... Otherwise there is way too may options from SQL servers of all kinds to other types of storage like [ReDis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) or [NoSQL DBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)  to suggest "best" in form acceptable for SO.

Comment: Databases do not just rewrite the whole database whenever you perform an action. Databases are monstrosities of efficiencies and there are tons of long, very long articles on how they perform those actions, oh-so effectively. So who ever told you that - he's wrong.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I'm looking for the fastest way to do this, and that's also why I posted this question - maybe DBs are faster?

Comment: @Yorye Nathan wow that's good to know - Does this apply to a basic SQL server too?

Comment: It does. DB's are certainly faster than using a file system (textfiles etc). I recommend SQL Server because it is great as a database and fairly simple to learn and dive into. You can start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EpYqtSlOr8).

Comment: @Yorye Nathan Perfect - that's what I'm gonna use then. Thank you!

Comment: I load 1,029 XML files, each about 135kB in 7.4 seconds. If your code doesn't need to load every user each time and you are only adding information sporadically then a bunch of XML files per user could be a simple easy way to start. This approach could then map nicely to a document DB in the future.

Comment: @Chester "looking for fastest" and pick SQL server that can't be (by design) the fastest option due to [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) requirement... How that can be non-opinion based I have no idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most effective is highly subjective based on who you ask even if narrowing down this question to specific needs.  If you are storing non-relational data Mongo or some other NoSQL type of database such as Raven DB would be effective.  If your data has a relational shape then an RDBMS such as MySQL, SQL Server, or Oracle would be effective.  Relational databases are ideal if you are going to have heavy reporting requirements as this allows non-developers more ease of access in writing simple SQL queries against it. But also keeping in mind performance with disk cache persistence that databases provide. Commonly accessed data is stored in memory to save the round trips to the disk (with hybrid drives I suppose accessing some files directly accomplishes the same thing however SSD's are still not as fast as RAM access). So you really need to ask yourself some questions to identify the best solution for you; What is the shape of your data (flat, relational, etc), do you have reporting requirements where less technical team members need to be able to query the data repository, and what are your performance metrics?

Comment: As described in my question, I have users, some properties, statistics (logins/outs, etc.) and maybe some other data bound to them. So I think I'm going to go with an SQL Database, as this looks most attractive to me (-> comments of question)